# Grant all users access to a folder (including new files)

Tags: command-line, 16.04, permissions, samba, gnome-terminal

I've got a task running to take files from a share on one server and move them to a share on another server. However, I receive permissions errors when trying to move `.new` files in the source share and I'm having to run the following command each time, before the task runs.

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /path/to/folder
```

Is there a command I can run which would instantly give all users access to any new files created in the source directory?

Ubuntu Version: 16.04 LTS

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: [set default permission](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: @K7AAY isn't it better to implement that in the ask Q form instead, by now you have to realize its a lost cause reminding everyone.

Comment: @bac0n I'm so glad you agree with the need to make this consistently applied. See my suggestion to do that at https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18979/use-of-new-screening-tool-from-se And, no, it hasn't been a lost cause. I've seen an uptick of folks stating their OS and version since I started asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your are looking for [umask](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uumask.htm) mecanism. It sets  the value of the system's file mode creation mask.

Welcome on Askubuntu =)

Comment: Consider expanding the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about setting this?